# Sending array of objects via POST not working - Angular

Tags: json, angular, post, content-type

I cannot send an array of `FormGroup` objects to my backend.

**Error**: It says: `"Unsupported Media Type" "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"` error 415.

---

Previously, it could not deserialize the array into my Java object in my backend because it was not in JSON format, and now I am stuck with this.

I have tried to use `JSON.stringify(arrayOfFormGroups)` to convert it to JSON, but I do not know why it says I am sending `plain/text`.

---

This code gives you the content type error.

**TS**

```
// Inserts all the form data into one array
let dataArray: String[] = [this.form1.value, this.form2.value, this.form3.value, this.form4.value];

// Send the form data to the service, which then sends the data to the server (Spring-Boot)
this.data.sendFormData(JSON.stringify(dataArray)).subscribe(
      response => console.log("Success! ", response),
      error => console.error("Error: ", error)
    );
}
```

This code makes the array undeserializable for consumption in the backend.

**TS**

```
// Inserts all the form data into one array
let dataArray: String[] = [this.form1.value, this.form2.value, this.form3.value, this.form4.value];

// Send the form data to the service, which then sends the data to the server (Spring-Boot)
this.data.sendFormData(dataArray).subscribe(
      response => console.log("Success! ", response),
      error => console.error("Error: ", error)
    );
}
```

**Service**

```
sendFormData(userData) {
   return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/create", userData);
}
```

---

**Expected**

I want to POST my array of FormGroups to my backend as JSON String.

**Actual**

An error occurs when I POST, unsupported `content-type plain/text` even though I am sending JSON.

Comment: You shouldn't stringify it, that's why Angular thinks it's plain text. It's unclear what the deserialisation problem was, did you check whether the *payload* was as expected?

Comment: It could not `deserialize` it because it was not in JSON format.

Comment: When? *Before* you started stringifying it? What *was* being sent?

Comment: Yes, before I was stringifying it. I cannot send the array just as it is or it gives me an error.

Comment: Maybe you should show a [mcve] of that, because the behaviour you're describing here is as expected.

Comment: I added both cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196429/discussion-between-compiler-v2-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: And how do you expect that to help? What actually gets *sent*? What payload, what content type? And what exactly happens in the backend? What does the backend even look like? What's the *right* payload? Have you sent it successfully with a *different* client (e.g. Postman)? It's not even clear you're looking at the right side of the problem right now.

Comment: Nothing gets sent. The payload is the array with the FormGroups & the content I believe is an object. In my backend, I am using a RESTful service with Spring boot and I am using controllers to retrieve the data. The right payload is JSON. I have not sent it via a different client like Postman. My backend works completely fine (I ran tests with just the URL), it is just my payload that is not being sent.

Comment: as @jonrsharpe suggested, try to use curl, POSTMan or Jmeter to send your test json payload to your backend....to see it it goes though. If it is, then compare the http request from your testing with actual http request being generated by angular app and see whats different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to store the data into an object, not an array. The reason is that you cannot send a JSON array to your backend if it only consumes one single object. They are incompatible.

**TS**

```
 // User object
  private user = {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
 };

....

// Populates the user object
this.user.firstName = this.form1.controls['firstName'].value;
this.user.lastName = this.form2.controls['lastName'].value;

// Sends the form data to the service
this.data.sendFormData(JSON.stringify(this.user)).subscribe(
   response => console.log("Success! ", response),
   error => console.error("Error: ", error)
);
```

I am using multiple form groups because I am using Angular material's stepper in linear mode, which requires each step to have its own FormGroup.

More on that: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#linear-stepper

Also, I had to add a header to my POST:

**My Service**

```
private header = new HttpHeaders({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() { }

sendFormData(userData) {
  return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/createAccount", userData, { headers: this.header });
}
```

**Good reading on converting objects to JSON VS arrays to JSON:** https://alligator.io/js/json-parse-stringify/